# Как получить реф ссылку после запуска приложения скачанного в плей маркете

Tags: unity3d, google-play, playmarket

Доброго времени суток.
Помогите разобраться..
Делаю игру для андроид в Unity и партнерку.
Для каждого пользователя при первом запуске игры на сервере генерится реф id и вставляется в ссылку для приглашения друзей и тд. и получения бонуса.
Ссылка https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=blablabla&referrer=RefID
Как получить RefID в скрипте?
В гугле инфы хватает. Но, то не работает - устарело. То заточено под другие ЯП..

Comment: https://android-tools.ru/coding/kak-polzovatsya-google-play-install-referrer/

Comment: @Style-7гугл перекопал вдоль и поперек.. но как интегрировать Google Play Install Referrer в unity не нашел. В файле build.gradle даже намека на dependencies {} нету.

Comment: если даже по такой обучлке не можете сделать наверное лучше нанять кого-то

Comment: обучалка? вы это серьезно?)) цитирую:  откройте файл build.gradle модуля приложения и добавьте следующую строчку в блок dependencies. так вот в UNITY это НЕ работает.  нужно создать экземпляр класса InstallReferrerClient. посмотрите в доках содержимое класса.. коротко - в юньке код с "обучалки" работать НЕ будет

Comment: да, вы правы ...